# AdaBoost - How to use the distribution D

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, adaboost

I am tying to implement AdaBoost algorithm in Python.

I have m weak classifiers in list called `classifiers`.
I have vector _D with values of the distribution for current iteration.
My code looks like this (the vectors are numpy arrays):

```
for t in range(m):
  chosen_examples_indexes = []
  for i, d in enumerate(_D):
    if np.random.binomial(1, d) == 1:
      chosen_examples_indexes.append(i)
    training_examples = examples[chosen_examples_indexes]
```

The quesion is whether the use of _D iw correct. If no, what is the correct usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdaBoost in its core version uses distribution D to **weight** your samples, and not sample them (although in the limit this is pretty much the same, in the fixed length scenario this is completely different).

Thus in your notation you would simply do

```
X, y = # get training data from examples
for t in range(m):
    classifiers[t].fit(X, y, sample_weights=_D)
    # update _D based on results
```

if your classifier does not support sample_weights then it is more problematic, and solution is more or less as you provided, however weighting should be always **prefered** if only possible, as it is a direct optimization of what we are interested in, not a stochastic approximation (which comes from sampling).

```
for t in range(m):
    chosen_examples_indexes = np.array([np.random.random() < _d for _d in _D])
    training_examples = examples[chosen_examples_indexes]
    X, y = # get training data from training_examples
    classifiers[t].fit(X, y)
    # update _D based on results
```

Comment: I am using SVM with SubGradiend Descent, written by me. How to add weights for it?

Comment: SVM can easily incorporate weights, as your cost is in the form of `||w||^2 + C SUM_i hinge_loss( <w, x_i> + b, y_i )` so the only thing you do is to change loss to  `||w||^2 + C SUM_i D_i hinge_loss( <w, x_i> + b, y_i )`, thus each component of your gradient belonging to i'th trianing sample will be weighted by weight of this sample, that's all!

Comment: Thanks!! About the `b`, I don't know how to find value for it, so I just put `b=0`. What is the correct method?

Comment: if you are solving in primal, then it is just a parameter, like 'w', but not regularized. In dual it actually does not matter and is reconstructed in the end (as you know that SUM alpha_j y_j K(x_j, x_i) + b = y_i for support vectors thus b = mean_i y_i - (SUM alpha_j y_j K(x_j, x_i)) ).

Comment: Gradient on dual should be inefficient but possible

Comment: And finding `b` in primal, SubGradient Descent is good? I just have to calc d(loss) / d(b) ?